# Rewrite htacess rule doesn't work

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

Inside the **page** directory I have multiple pages such as admin-add-account, registration, and I'm trying to rename them from [www.example.com/page/admin-add-account.php](http://www.example.com/page/admin-add-account.php) to [www.example.com/admin-add-account](http://www.example.com/admin-add-account). I've tried this but it's not working, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /page/

RewriteRule ^register/?$ registration.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^forget-password/?$ forget-password.php [L,NC]
# ignore files/directories from further rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Why don't you use WP as  CMS to create and manage the rewrites?

Comment: @QStudio because it's not working for these examples and I would like to do it manually

Comment: Then, you'll need to explain a little more about your setup, it seems counter-intuitive at the moment - remember WP has it's own rewrite with rules, are you adding your before or after these?

Comment: @QStudio after wp it's doing the rewrite

Comment: Can you explain more, show errors, show what else you have tried, show the full .htacess or give anything else that might help answer your question - out of context, the code might be "right", but it might simply conflict with something else.

Comment: @QStudio edited the post and now you have all the htaccess file. There is no error, it's just showing me the link with .php and not the link without php

Comment: @RobinsonChera this can't be done using HTAccess as those are WP rewrite rules. I assume `registration.php` is not a direct URL to a PHP file? But rather a slug of a permalink?

Comment: @RobinsonChera You seem to have logged in (and commenting) as a different user?

Comment: @RobinsonChera Where is this `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MrWhite yes, I didn't use my main account to post this

Comment: @RobinsonChera But why? You're not going to get the same notifications and privileges (ie. ability to edit your question, accept answers, etc.) unless you switch back. I see you've tried to edit your question as your other user, now the edit is stuck in a queue and could be rejected. And can you please clarify exactly where the `.htaccess` file is located on the filesystem that you've posted in your question. Is it in the document root or in the `/page` subdirectory?

Comment: @MrWhite it's in the index_html folder, so basically in the root folder of the website

Comment: There appears to be several inconsistencies here... how does this relate to WordPress? Where is the WP front-controller in `.htaccess`? Where is WP installed? Are you using pretty permalinks? We need to see your complete `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Did  you have the answer to any of the questions I asked? Is `registration.php` a physical file on the filesystem? Or is it a WordPress post/page?